# Delete row from UITableView NSMutableArray and ManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsmutablearray, entity-relationship

I've got the UITableView which is populated from NSMutableArray. 
NSMutableArray was created from my NSFetchedResultsController which came from another view

```
  Templates *template2 = (Templates *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        qModalView.templateObject = template2;
```

and was recorded to templateObject, so I have got all my objects in this my NSMutablArray that way.

[templateObject.questions allObjects];

Now I want to delete row in my table view , in array and in that particular object in templateObject.questions.

Please help, I have this so far:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Questions *question_var = [questionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"_____________________________%@", question_var.question_title);

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [templateObject managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[templateObject.questions objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }else{
        NSLog(@"deleted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the row from the table with

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                 withRowAnimation:YES];
```

and you can delete an object from an `NSMutableArray` with

```
[myArray removeObject:myObject];
```

Comment: and how do I delete it from the database? Is it happening automatically?

Comment: You've already got the database delete, in the lines "[context deleteObject:[templateObject.questions objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
" and "[context save:&error]".